# Проблема миграции в Laravel. Ошибка 3780

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

При попытке миграции возникает ошибка

> General error: 3780 Referencing column 'id_user' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'userlist_id_user_foreign' are incompatibl
> e. (SQL: alter table `userlist` add constraint `userlist_id_user_foreign` foreign key (`id_user`) references `users` (`id`))

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('list_films', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('img');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('login');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('img');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('userlist', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('id_user');
            $table->bigInteger('id_list');
            $table->primary(['id_user', 'id_list']);
            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('id_list')->references('id')->on('list_films');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Изначально типы данных у меня действительно не совпадали, но поменяв `id_user` и `id_list` на `bigInteger` ошибка не исчезла. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: bigIncrements - это unsigned int (+), а bigInteger - просто int(+ ИЛИ -), поменяйте на unsignedBigInteger().

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Действительно, поменяв метод на bigInteger и добавив autoIncrement() все заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: @Клешня Сейчас вообще лучше так по связям заводить, и писать меньше на одну строку, и шанс ошибиться сильно ниже: `$table->foreignId('id_user')->nullable()->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade');`